# Html and javascript <select> tags with filtering

Tags: javascript, html, select, html-select

I will try to be as specific as I can.

So I need to create a selector that filters the options.

I have:

1. types of cars
2. The places where you can drive those cars.

So for example you would select > Ferrari > then the correct areas on the second select tag show up

I.e.  Select > Ferrari = London, Cambridge, Devon, New hampshire

```
  Select > Lamborghini = London, Bertshire, Oakwood,
```

And then finally

they choose (Ferrari + Cambridge) and then press "go" and jump to the final link that will take them to the right page.

My code is:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 




$('#filter-regions').on('click', function() {
    var pilotage-carFilter = $('#pilotage-car').text();
    var itemFilter = $('#items').text(); 

    console.log('pilotage-carFilter: ' + pilotage-carFilter);
    console.log('itemFilter : ' + itemFilter);
    console.log('Applying filter now...');

    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        console.log('Running filter() on item: ('+item+')');
        console.log('item.values().pilotage-car: ' + item.values().pilotage-car);
        console.log('item.values().item: ' + item.values().item);

        return 
            (pilotage-carFilter==='Ferrari' || item.values().pilotage-car === pilotage-carFilter) 
            && (itemFilter==='All items' || item.values().item === itemFilter);
    });

    return false;
});



//]]>  

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form id="filter">
<select id="pilotage-car" name="pilotage-car" size="1">
<option value="http://www.coolcadeau.fr/Stage-de-pilotage-Ferrari-BN-5iZ5.aspx?SqNo=5iZ5&cm_sp=LHN-_-Voiture-_-Ferrari&cm_re=Ferrari-_-Voiture-_-LHN">Ferrari</option>
<option value="Porsche">Porsche</option>
<option value="Lamborghini" selected>Lamborghini</option>
<option value="Mustang">Mustang</option>
<option value="Audi" selected>Audi</option>
<option value="Multivolants">Multivolants</option>
<option value="Rallye">Rallye</option>
<option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
<option value="Karting">Karting</option>
<option value="4x4">4x4</option>
<option value="Moto">Moto</option>
<option value="Quad">Quad</option>
<option value="Buggy">Buggy</option>
<option value="Renault Sport">Renault Sport</option>
<option value="Prototype">Prototype</option>
<option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
<option value="Corvette">Corvette</option>
</select>

<select id="items" name="items" size="1">
<option value="http://www.coolcadeau.fr/Stage-de-pilotage-Ferrari-Alsace-BN-5iZ5Z1z13skq.aspx?SqNo=5iZ5Z1z13skq&cm_sp=LHN-_-Region-_-Alsace&cm_re=Alsace-_-Region">A l'&eacute;tranger</option>
<option value="Alsace">Alsace</option>
<option value="Aquitaine" selected>Aquitaine</option>
<option value="Auvergne">Auvergne</option>
<option value="Basse-Normandie" selected>Basse-Normandie</option>
<option value="Bourgogne">Bourgogne</option>
<option value="Bretagne">Bretagne</option>
<option value="Centre">Centre</option>
<option value="Champagne-Ardenne">Champagne-Ardenne</option>
<option value="Franche-Comt&eacute;">Franche-Comt&eacute;</option>
<option value="Haute-Normandie">Haute-Normandie</option>
<option value="Ile-de-France">Ile-de-France</option>
<option value="Languedoc-Roussillon">Languedoc-Roussillon</option>
<option value="Limousin">Limousin</option>
<option value="Lorraine">Lorraine</option>
<option value="Midi-Pyr&eacute;n&eacute;es">Midi-Pyr&eacute;n&eacute;es</option>
<option value="Nord-Pas-de-Calais">Nord-Pas-de-Calais</option>
<option value="Pays de la Loire">Pays de la Loire</option>
<option value="Picardie">Picardie</option>
<option value="Poitou-Charentes">Poitou-Charentes</option>
<option value="Provence-Alpes-C&ocirc;te d'Azur">Provence-Alpes-C&ocirc;te d'Azur</option>
<option value="Rh&ocirc;ne-Alpes">Rh&ocirc;ne-Alpes</option>
</select>




<input id="go-button" type="button" name="test" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Im really not sure about javascript at all.

**How could I, and/or what is the best way I could achieve this? Are there any examples out there?**

EDIT: I found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dtAgX/1/
      But i need a sumbit button that will link to the right page based on selection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so whats the question? this site is not for gathering code but to get help with a specific problem

Comment: Sorry my question is basically how do I make a selector that can perform like in the first few sentences I explained?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options depending on your backend, PHP, ASP ect. or plain HTML.
If you use PHP/ASP you can provide an 'action' and a 'method' for your  and have the server provide the correct page, depending on the values of your selects.

If you use plain HTML, you can add an 'onsubmit' event to your  and have a javascript redirect to the correct page.

In both cases the "go-button" should be of type "submit".

If you want more help I'll need to know more about your setup :-)

Also, can all cars be driven at all locations?

Comment: Hi, thanks.the site im doing it for is http://www.coolcadeau.fr/ They actually use aspx. And only certain cars can be driven in certain loctions. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3yKJ7/3/)
Sorry, I'm not to good with aspx.
The function update1, will modify which options that are valid on the second select. Here you shoud insert your own script.

Comment: hi thanks for this. It put things in a better perspective. But where do i add all the links?

Comment: The links could be added through the server side script, or though Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/4BVfJ/

Comment: @user3099325 Any luck?